# Wrong reprojecting of a shapefile with to_crs in GeoPandas

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

When reprojecting an ESRI Shapefile (EPSG:21781) into an EPSG:4326 with QGIS and then importing the resulting file in GeoPandas and plotting it, the coordinates are correct.

[image: Correct projection]

When importing the same shapefile directly in GeoPandas and then reprojecting it using `to_crs({'init', 'EPSG:4326'})`, there is a slight offset.

[image: Incorrect projection]

Here is the result of `my_shapefile.crs`:

```
{
  'ellps': 'bessel',
  'k_0': 1,
  'lat_0': 46.95240555555556,
  'lon_0': 7.439583333333333,
  'no_defs': True,
  'proj': 'somerc',
  'units': 'm',
  'x_0': 600000,
  'y_0': 200000
}
```

I don't understand if I missed a step with the CRS conversion in GeoPandas or if the `to_crs` function needs another parameter.

Comment: [@Zamadhi Eturu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/114239/zamadhi-eturu), what if you check the original projection of your shapefile directly with GeoPandas, i.e. `your_shapefile_.crs`? What does it say?

Comment: I think you just missed one apostrophe at the end of your quotation marks in the following statement `to_crs({'init', 'EPSG:4326})`, which should be `to_crs({'init', 'EPSG:4326'})`, and therefore GeoPanda visualizes it in original EPSG:21781.

Comment: That reprojection requires datum transformation. It's possible that geopandas is ignoring transformation.

Comment: @Taras, I updated my original post

Comment: I think [@Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince) is right

Comment: Well, instead of converting my EPSG:21781 polygons into EPSG:4326, I converted my EPSG:4326 points into the same CRS as my polygons (which is EPSG:21781) and it worked... Any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: Looking at http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/ch1903-lv03/ and your crs dictionary is it possible that geopandas somehow doesn't recognize the correct crs? What happens if you explicitly set the correct epsg code again before doing any reporjection? so shapefile.crs = {'init', 'EPSG:21781}  and then reproject to 4326 as usual.

Comment: @ChristophRieke you are right. I just explicitly set the correct epsg code right after loading the file and the projection is now correct.

Comment: Cool, same happended to me once too. Would also be curious if anyone has an idea how this can happen, especially because QGIS seems to handle this correctly.

Comment: @Vince GeoPandas uses pyproj / proj4 under the hood, and as far as I know, those can do datum transformations.

Comment: @ChristophRieke if you would be able to provide a reproducible example (eg a small shapefile that reproduces the problem, or one you had it before with that you are able to share), opening an issue about this on https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas would be very welcome

Comment: @joris Sorry, unfortunately (or fortunately..) not able to replicate it. Maybe you need to update your geopandas/pyproj Zahmadi Eturu.